# locationManager function triggered at end of code

Tags: swift, ios9, core-location, locationmanager

I'm trying to get my code to pick up the user's current location and send it off to a server. When I run my code it seems like the `LocationManager` function only fires after everything in my `startload` function is completed. I'm trying to get the user's location *before* the data is sent to the server.

```
class ViewController: .....
    var currentLoc = "0"
    [...]
    func startload(place: String){ // Starts the process, send recording data and location to node
            // GETS LOCATION
            print(place)
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestLocation()
            print("Just req location")
            // GETS LOCATION
            // SENDS REQUEST
            // create the request & response
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://4890adf2.ngrok.io/ios")!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
            var response: NSURLResponse?

            // create some JSON data and configure the request
            print("preping json")
            let jsonString = "json={\"location\":\"\(currentLoc)\", \"Place\": \" \(place) \"}"
            request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            // send the request
            print("Sending the request")
            do{
                let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
                let datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Datastring: \(datastring!)")
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
            // look at the response
            //print("The response: \(response)")
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print("HTTP response: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            } else {
                print("No HTTP response")
            }
            // SENDS REQUEST
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            print("Inside LocationManager")
            if let location = locations.first {
                currentLoc = String(location)
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
            print("Error finding location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

I've tried adding `sleep()` after `locationManager.requestLocation()` to see if I could try halting execution until the `locationManager` function is fired off, but even when sleeping it still doesn't trigger.

the console output looks like:

```
First hit
restaurant
Just req location
preping json
Sending the request
Datastring: HTTP 200
HTTP response: 200
Inside LocationManager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it wrong. `LocationManager` is a asynchronous API that gives you call back on delegate method once it has something to tell you.

Do not write your program sequentially thinking it will immediately give you data.

Align you code as per `LocationManager` implementation by iOS and move your server call in `didUpdateLocations` API. **Beware, this method gets called multiple times as per location change, so, you might want to double check when and what data you want to send to server.**

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "move your server call in didUpdateLocations?"

Comment: I meant - you should wait until `LocationManager` calls the delegate method `didUpdateLocations `. Once you have data available then only make server call to post that data on server.